# How to sync vocals in Pro Tools using a plugin?

Tags: mixing, pro-tools, sync, vocals, plugins

I'm mixing an acapella choir in pro tools with 20 tracks. There are a lot of times when one singer or another isn't singing the same rhythm as others.

I know there is a plugin that can sync the rhythm in different tracks together.
Anyone know it?

Answer (score 1):

Re: @coaxmw 's answer

Both VocAlign & Re-Voice are good tools, but I'd be careful of 'over-aligning' a choir - I once did it [with VocAlign] & ended up with 80 tracks that sounded like 6 people & had to start over to preserve the 'size' of the end result.
A choir really doesn't align that precisely, even when they're 'good'.

Melodyne might be a better bet, though more manual to implement, you have more flexibility over how much to push each syllable/word/phrase.

Sometimes it might be better to just align the more noticeable aspects, P's, T's, S's etc & allow other segments a little more freedom.

One trick is to group the tracks & give them all an identical tiny fade out at the ends of phrases, based on the tracks closest to your intended phrasing. The artificial endings imposed on subordinate tracks will really not be noticed [caveat for phrases ending in a P or T, of course]

All this, of course, depends on just how close the original takes were in the first place - if they were miles out from each other, then some manual cut/timestretch/paste might be the quickest start-point.

Comment: Thanks guys. VocAlign. i remember know...i left a lot of breath to make it more human, but i just dont have the time (or really, not in the budget) to edit every track to sync syllables.

Answer (score 0):

Vocalign or Re-voice pro will are both worth trying.

Comment: Both good tools, but I'd be careful of 'over-aligning' a choir - I once did it [with VocAlign] & ended up with 80 tracks that sounded like 6 people & had to start over to preserve the 'size' of the end result. A choir really doesn't align that precisely, even when they're 'good'. Melodyne might be a better bet, though more manual to implement, you have more flexibility over 'how much'

Answer (score 0):

You may try a simple sidechain gate/expander setup. I used this to control dubs several times with success.

1. Pick out one or two good takes/sources and create an aux copy called "Lead Vox" of those (i.e. send them to the same Aux Bus)
2. Route *all* vocal tracks to the same group, lets call it "Choir".
3. On the "Choir" group add a sidechainable gate/expander
4. Assign the "Lead Vox" aux to the sidechain input of the gate/expander and tweak threshold to a low point so it opens immediately. If it has release/hold/decay settings make sure they're very short.

This way you "sync" the start and ending of all the sources with just one or two, and you won't loose the wide image choiry image that arise from not having perfectly aligned phrases etc.